# Remove custom http header from future requests in .net web api

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, http-headers, owin

I've added a custom header `X-XSRF-TOKEN` and when a user logs out I want to be able to remove that header from future requests sent by the browser.

In the logout web api action I can modify the header like so:

```
Request.GetOwinContext().Response.Headers.Append("X-XSRF-TOKEN", "ModifiedToken");
```

On future requests it now sends requests with the `X-XSRF-TOKEN` with the value `ModifiedToken`. Is there a way I can remove it instead. With cookies you can expire them.

If I call the remove function on the Request or Response headers, on the next request to the server the header is still present:

```
Request.GetOwinContext().Response.Headers.Remove("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
```

or

```
Request.GetOwinContext().Request.Headers.Remove("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
```

Is it even possible to do this or even guarantee the browser will actually stop sending the header?

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

Request.GetOwinContext().Response.Headers.Append("NULL", "ModifiedToken");

Note - I am not sure it will work or not. But you can try this one as well.